# Artifactory proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, artifactory

Im trying to place my artifactory installation behind a Apache reverse proxy. Im doing this for several reasons:

- I want to get rid of the port number in the url
- I want to use apache to provide SSL
- I want to get rid of the /artifactory part of the url

I have managed the first two but the last step is eluding me.

I basicly want my url to me https://artifactory.domain.tld and not https://artifactory.domain.tld/artifactory

This is my vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on
    Protocol https
    ServerName servername:443
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/server.cer"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/server.key"

    SSLProxyEngine          On
    ProxyRequests           Off
    ProxyPreserveHost       On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
</virtualhost>
```

Im running on Windows, Apache version 2.4 and Artifactory version 3.3.0

Any help or pointers appriciated.

Comment: This seems to be a none issue in more recent versions of Artifactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory/api/docker/<repository key>
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory/api/docker/<repository key>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify your `ProxyPass` directives to the below:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory/
```

Comment: This dos not work.
I get this error in FF
    {"errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "/artifactory/artifactory/webapp"
    }  ]
    }
It seem the "artifactory" part is something that is applied after the proxy part is completed by Apache. So my guess at the moment is that it is a Artifactory setting or a tomcat setting that is the culprit.